# How to unstack data with more than two columns into several columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a table that contains three columns displayed in picture 1 and I want to change the table layout into the one shown in picture 2 by power query. Usually, the table comes with more than 500 PO numbers so it will be really tedious to do it manually.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: In second picture "Po number" column is containing "Size 1", "Size 2", "Size 3" etc. It's completely different layout then in first picture.

Comment: If data order doesn't matter 1) sort your data by PO number 2) add a helper column (po line) with a formula that will increment/reset for each row of a particular PO, 3) pivot the data with PO as row, PO line as the column, and size and quantity as data values.

Comment: The closest one I can get is the table shown in picture 3 but I have to split each column manually and rename it. I wonder if there is a smarter way to do that.

Comment: Hi @JohnHuang,, now check my post I've solved the issue by using Excel formula. ☺

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

- It is kind of a reverse of the process used to go from your desired results to your source data.
- The "tricky" part that needs to be done from the Advanced Editor is to generate a running count of entries by PO Number, so as to dynamically generate the repeated column numbers (*there may be more efficient ways of doing this*)

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"PO Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

       //Generate running count by PO Number to use for new column names
        group = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"PO Number"}, {"temp", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Counter",1,1)}),
        expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(group, "temp", {"Counter", "Attribute","Value"}),
        
       //Integer-Divide the running count for the column suffix 
        #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(expand, "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Counter]+1.5, 2), Int64.Type),
        
       //Merge with the base column name 
        #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Integer-Division", "colNames", each Text.Combine({[Attribute], Text.From([#"Integer-Division"], "en-US")}, " "), type text),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Counter", "Attribute", "Integer-Division"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"PO Number", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[colNames]), "colNames", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

[image]

***Note:** The above was written given your data, where all values are numeric. However, if some of the sizes are alphanumeric (eg 40W), then the size columns need to be typed as text and the order columns, presumably, as numbers. If that is the case, the code below will take that into account:*

**M Code** *modified to allow Size columns to be text, and OrderQty columns number*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"PO Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

       //Generate running count by PO Number to use for new column names
        group = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"PO Number"}, {"temp", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Counter",1,1)}),
        expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(group, "temp", {"Counter", "Attribute","Value"}),
        
       //Integer-Divide the running count for the column suffix 
        #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(expand, "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Counter]+1.5, 2), Int64.Type),
        
       //Merge with the base column name 
        #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Integer-Division", "colNames", each Text.Combine({[Attribute], Text.From([#"Integer-Division"], "en-US")}, " "), type text),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Counter", "Attribute", "Integer-Division"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"PO Number", type text}, {"Value", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[colNames]), "colNames", "Value"),

        //Convert Orders to type whole number
        ordCols = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"), each Text.StartsWith(_,"ordered")),
        xForm = List.Zip({ordCols, List.Repeat({Int64.Type},List.Count(ordCols))}),
        typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column",xForm)
in
    typed
```

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest Excel formula driven method, needs few helper data.*

*A combination of INDEX & MATCH wrapped with IFERROR, using some helper data, extracts value in desire order.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- For helper data formula in cell D2 & fill it down:

  `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)`
- Enter Helper value as showm in G1:N1.
- The array (CSE) formula in cell F3, gets unique PO list.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$2:F2, $A$2:$A$11), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell G3, and fill across.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(IF(OR(G$2="Size1",G$2="Size2",G$2="Size3",G$2="Size4"),INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(1,($F3=$A$2:$A$11)*(G$1=$D$2:$D$11),0)),INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(1,($F3=$A$2:$A$11)*(G$1=$D$2:$D$11),0))),0)}
  ```

**N.B**

- *Finish array formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.*
- *In second array formula you can replace last  `,0)}` with `,"")}`.*
- *For neatness you may hide Helper data.*
- *You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*